# How to open a window and tab in Terminal via Javascript automation

Tags: terminal, applescript, script, javascript-automation

I want to use the Script Editor program to create a script (Javascript) that will recreate my Terminal window and tab setup. I open a few windows, open tabs within those windows, label the tabs, run some commands.

My problem is that I don't understand how to read these "dictionaries" in the Script Editor. For example, it doesn't say anywhere how to open a new window or a tab.

Here are screenshots from the Script Editor's window showing the dictionary for the Terminal app.

[image]

[image]

I can get the app, by saying:

```
var terminal = Application("Terminal")
```

So:

1. How do you open windows and tabs?
2. How do you learn how to this? Is it in the dictionary somewhere, or somewhere else?